# How to change the display format of date in react-intl?

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, react-intl

I need to display the date using different separators using react-intl.
So far I have this

```
const date = new Date("2016-08-12T16:59:02.013+02:00");
...
return() {
   render(
      <FormattedDate
            value={date}
            year='numeric'
            month='numeric'
            day='numeric'
          />
   )
}
```

This renders the date **8/12/2016**, but I need to show it like this **8-12-2016**.
How can this be done with FormattedDate? Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: Use localeMatcher="lookup" and locale="en-in".

Answer (score 1):

First, import the [hoc](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.xuwbcncxu) from react-intl package:

```
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl'
```

then apply it to your component:

```
injectIntl(YourReactComponent)
```

It will give you access to the [`formatDate`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatdate) method via the `props` in `YourReactComponent`. The method is used internally by instances of `FormattedDate` and it returns the string representation of the formatted date:

```
  const stringDate = this.props.intl.formatDate(date, // your date variable
            {
                year:'numeric',
                month:'numeric',
                day:'numeric'
            })
```

`stringDate` now contains `8/12/2016`, you can modify it as you like:

```
const stringWithHyphens = stringDate.replace(/\//g, "-"); // replacing all '/'s with '-'s
```